# Change button in ngFor list to text field to take value and then submit for processing

Tags: javascript, angular, list, angular5

First off, I'm loving Angular 2 (v5). Taken a while to "get it" but suddenly it's all made sense and really enjoying working with it.

I have a list of products generated from a WebApi service that I load into an Observable array and display on the UI using ngFor. Very simple stuff. Each item has a button to Add to Cart. Again simple and all working great.

What I want to do is make the process a bit more fluid for a user, so when a users clicks the Add to Cart button, the button is hidden and a number input spinner is revealed with an Add button, so that the user can simply select quantity at this point, prior to submitting to the AddToCart function. Otherwise they have to add to cart, then update the quantity.

I'm having a "brain not working" moment, if I'm showing and hiding elements within a ngFor list using Angular 5 with perhaps an ngIf, how do I identify that unique element or should I just use some standard JavaScript for this and if so what's the unique identifier for the element? Obviously it won't work with a variable at component level as that affects every button in the list. Perhaps I shouldn't be considering Angular at all for manipulating the DOM in this instance.

I can take the productID from the model and append that to the ID field for the button giving it an ID of something like "btn_000142" and giving the hidden element an ID of "quantity_000142" and then when the button is clicked I use some javascript (or jQuery?) to show and hide and then pass the value with the object back into the component code. But is that the right way to handle this?

Probably a stupid question, just sometimes it's hard to break the "just throw some jQuery at it" or "in MVC I'd do that easily like this..." thinking pattern! :)

Some code below:

```
<div *ngFor="let prod of prodDetails$ | async" [@fadeInOut] class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
  <div class="card h-100">
      <a routerLink="{{prod.productWebFriendlyName}}"><img class="card-img-top" [src]="prod.productImgUrl" alt=""></a>
          <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">
                    <a routerLink="{{prod.productWebFriendlyName}}">{{ prod.productName }}</a>
                </h4>
                <p class="card-text">{{ prod.productDescription }}</p>
                <p class="card-text">{{ prod.productPrice | currency:'GBP' }} 
                  <!-- click this button to display the div below and hide this button-->
                  <button type="button" (click)="addToCart(prod)" class="btn btn-primary float-right small">Add to Cart</button> 
                  <!-- This is hidden until the Add to Cart is clicked -->
                  <div id="numberSpinnnerHere" style="display:none">NUMBER SPINNER HERE <button id="FinalAddToCartWithQuantity(prod, quantity)">Add</button></div></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: where is the component code? what is the addToCart function? you can use ngIf on the numberSpinner and when the addToCart function run it shows the number spinner for the product.

Comment: Sorry didn't post the component code as it's just a skeleton at the moment, addToCart just pushes the product into a holding array and updates the total items in the cart count in a BehaviorSubject that the navigation bar subscribes to to keep a count of items in the cart. @manzur-khan-sarguroh code seemed to do exactly what I was trying to achieve, I just had to think outside the MVC/jQuery box I was stuck in! The scope of "prod" in the ngFor was what I'd missed. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in this way (trimmed the code for clearity)

```
<div *ngFor="let prod of prodDetails$ | async; let i = index" [@fadeInOut]>
      <div class="card h-100">
          <a routerLink="{{prod.productWebFriendlyName}}"></a>
              <div class="card-body">
                      <!-- click this button to display the div below and hide this button-->
                      <button *ngIf="!productAdded[i]" type="button" (click)="addToCart(prod, i)" class="btn btn-primary float-right small">Add to Cart</button> 
                      <!-- This is hidden until the Add to Cart is clicked -->
                      <div *ngIf="productAdded[i]" id="numberSpinnnerHere" style="display:none">NUMBER SPINNER HERE <button id="FinalAddToCartWithQuantity(prod, quantity)">Add</button></div></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Then in your component

```
productAdded = new Array(prodDetails.length)

addToCart(prod, index) {
     productAdded[index] = true
}
```

Comment: Thanks Manzur that worked for fixing the issue I was having, perfect. Given some more time, I'm going to move to @CHAZTATS suggestion of having a ProductCartComponent as that makes perfect sense going forward and should make life easier! :)

Comment: Cool, glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

> how do I identify that unique element

It's done for you in the ngFor.

`*ngFor="let prod of prodDetails`

prod is the object being iterated over in the list and is the only one in the scope when referring to prod.

So use some function like isProdInCart(prod) to determine whether to show the buttons.

Although saying this, if you made a ProductCardComponent you'd avoid most of the hassle of having to do that as your component could just have a flag or something that's set when the add to cart button is clicked.

Comment: I did wonder if there was something related to prod that I could use! It's so many years of MVC and jQuery and giving everything and ID manually... I had missed the scope when referring to "prod" in that instance even though I was passing it back to the TS code and seeing the entire model... DOH!! That's inspired with the ProductCardComponent, I will implement that, as you say it would make everything easier and also more manageable and makes so much more sense! . Thank you @CHAZTATS

Comment: No worries, my rule of thumb is if a component.ts file goes over 100 lines of code see if you can break it down even further.
Just for the sake of it most of the time.
good practice to help you keep things small and understandable.
Also try and keep as much logic as possible out of the HTML.
Again for just sheer simplicity.
Happy I helped :)

Comment: Cool, it's a learning curve but one I'm enjoying. So much power with Angular and the MVVM pattern, loving it! Thanks again!